# Any option other recursive search possible to go from one 2d point to another point with fixed set of possible moves?

Tags: graphs, search-algorithms, recursion

Problem:  Given (a,b) and (c,d), find if you can you reach from (a,b) to (c,d) if we can only have the following moves
(a, b) to either (a+b,b) or to (a,a+b).

Example (1,4) to (5,9) is possible because:  (1,4) -> (5,4) -> (5,9)

Solution:  I can think of is recursive search

```
Set 1: TestedPoints, initially empty
Set 2: PointsToTest, initially (a,b)

While (PointsToTest not empty):
   Remove nextPoint (x,y), 
   Compare (x+y,y) with (c,d):
          If x+y=c and y=d, return TRUE
          Else if x+y < c and y < d, add (x+y,y) to PointsTotest if it is not present in TestedPoints set

   Compare (x,x+y) with (c,d):
          If x=c and x+y=d, return TRUE
          Else if x < c and x+y < d, add (x,x+y) to PointsTotest if it is not present in TestedPoints set
```

Is there anything faster?

if we can express the progressive X,y points in an expression, I thunk we can do faster.  For e.g: Get a as close to c as possible and b as close to d as possible using equations and then do recursive search over smaller interval.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple method that is often faster: If you have $n$ moves to go from $A$ to $B$, determine the set of all points that you can reach from $A$ in $\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$ moves, and the set of all points from which $B$ can be reached in  $\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil$ moves, and then find if there are points in the intersection of these sets.

Answer (score 0):

**I'm assuming that $a,b,c$ and $d$ are positive natural numbers.**

Suppose that $(c,d)\neq(a,b)$.
Observe that if $a$ and $b$ are positive, then $(a+b,b)$ and $(a,a+b)$ are pairs of positive *distinct numbers*.
Hence if $c=d$, it is impossible to reach $(c,d)$.
Otherwise either $c>d$ or $c<d$.
Consider the case $c>d$ (the other case is similar).
If $(c,d)$ is reachable, consider the last transition: $(a',b')\to(c,d)$.
Since $c > d$ it must be the case that $c = a'+b'$ and $d=b'$.
Hence $a'=c-d$ and $b'=d$.
The key insight is that **the shape of the result "tells us" which rule must have generated it**.

So an adaptation of the Euclidean algorithm will be asymptotically faster.